# PHP - Array value access

Tags: php, arrays

I have defined arrays in my Symfony PHP function like:

```
public function getStats()
{
    return [
        'mainStats' => [
            'total' => $this->getTotal(),
            'balance' => $this->getBalance(),
        ],
        'all' => $this->getAll()
    ];
}
```

How can I access them so I can work with values. Like:

```
this->getStats()[0];
```

Comment: `$this->getStats()['mainStats']` and `$this->getStats()['all']`?

Comment: also you should pass the data with paramater

Comment: Though I would probably assign it to a variable first, if `getTotal()` or `getAll()` or `getBalance()` performs expensive operations.

Answer (score 2):

You can access it by keys you defined, like:

`$this->getStats()['mainStats']['total']`

`$this->getStatus()['all']`